# superclass method not being recognized in NodeJS inheritance

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

I am implementing the strategy design pattern in a nodeJS application. I have a base class Options, and a derived class accessToken. the derived class accessToken is supposed to override some of the Options settings, such as the body or URL of the HTTP request. When trying to run my application however, it appears that the derived class's extended methods (updateOptions() in particular) are not being recognized. running node app.js yields the following error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: accessObject.updateOptions is not a function
    at app.get (/Users/jorgevasquez/myProjects/myProjects/WebDev/teslaProject/app.js:31:16)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jorgevasquez/myProjects/myProjects/WebDev/teslaProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/jorgevasquez/myProjects/myProjects/WebDev/teslaProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/jorgevasquez/myProjects/myProjects/WebDev/teslaProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jorgevasquez/myProjects/myProjects/WebDev/teslaProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/jorgevasquez/myProjects/myProjects/WebDev/teslaProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/jorgevasquez/myProjects/myProjects/WebDev/teslaProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/jorgevasquez/myProjects/myProjects/WebDev/teslaProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at SendStream.error (/Users/jorgevasquez/myProjects/myProjects/WebDev/teslaProject/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:121:7)
    at SendStream.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at SendStream.error (/Users/jorgevasquez/myProjects/myProjects/WebDev/teslaProject/node_modules/send/index.js:270:17)
    at SendStream.onStatError (/Users/jorgevasquez/myProjects/myProjects/WebDev/teslaProject/node_modules/send/index.js:421:12)
    at next (/Users/jorgevasquez/myProjects/myProjects/WebDev/teslaProject/node_modules/send/index.js:763:28)
    at /Users/jorgevasquez/myProjects/myProjects/WebDev/teslaProject/node_modules/send/index.js:771:23
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)

Any hint as to what I'm doing incorrectly? Thanks!

Options.js

```
module.exports = class Options {

  construtor(){
    console.log("do nothing");
  }
   /**
   * Modify request type (i.e. GET, POST, etc.)
   */
   modifyRequestMethod() {
    throw new Error('You have to implement the method doSomething!');
 }

  /**
   * Modify URL
   */
  modifyUrl() {
    throw new Error('You have to implement the method doSomething!');
 }

 /**
  * Modify the request headers
  */
 modifyHeaders() {
    throw new Error('You have to implement the method doSomething!');
  }

  /**
   * Modify the request body
   */
  modifyBody(){
    throw new Error('You have to implement the method doSomething!');
  }

  updateOptions() {
    modifyRequestMethod();
    modifyUrl();
    modifyHeaders();
    modifyBody()
  }

  returnOptions() {
  return {
    url: this.requestURL,
    method: this.requestMethod,
    json: true,
    headers: this.requestHeaders,
    gzip: true,
    body: this.requestBody 
  };
}
}
```

accessToken.js

```
let optionsObj = require('./Options.js');
module.exports = class accessToken extends optionsObj {

    constructor() {
        console.log("Child");
        Options.apply(this, arguments);
        updateOptions();
        returnOptions(); 
    }


    modifyRequestMethod() {
        this.requestMethod = 'POST';
 }

    modifyUrl() {
        this.requestURL = 'https://owner-api.teslamotors.com/oauth/token';
 }

    modifyHeaders() {
        this.requestHeaders = {
        "x-tesla-user-agent": "TeslaApp/3.4.4-350/fad4a582e/android/8.1.0",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; Pixel XL Build/OPM4.171019.021.D1; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/68.0.3440.91 Mobile Safari/537.36",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "charset": "utf-8"
      }
  }

    modifyBody(){
        this.requestBody = {
        "grant_type": 'password',
        "client_id": '81527cff06843c8634fdc09e8ac0abefb46ac849f38fe1e431c2ef2106796384',
        "client_secret": 'c7257eb71a564034f9419ee651c7d0e5f7aa6bfbd18bafb5c5c033b093bb2fa3',
        "email": 'myEmail',
        "password": 'myPassword'
      };
  }

};
```

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
var path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var rp = require('request-promise');
const port = 3000;
let optionsObj = require('./helper/Options.js');
let accessObject = require('./helper/accessToken.js')
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
var accessToken;

app.get("/", async(req, resp) => {

  accessObject.updateOptions();
  const first_response = await rp(accessObject.returnOptions());
  myaccessToken = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(first_response))).access_token;

});

app.listen(port, () => {console.log('Example app listening on port ${port}!') } )
```

Comment: You have a typo: `construtor` should be `constructor`

Comment: You also have to call all methods (wither local or in the parent) with `this` as in `this.updateOptions();`.  You should also be using `super()` instead of manually calling the base constructor.  You're using the `class` keyword so you know that `super()` is there.